# ioncube decoded php web site cant load on localhost or in server

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, server, ioncube

i have php ecommerce web site and its encoded via ioncube.
ive decoded it and i had all codes to see clear but the problem is
if i decode it or change 
$domain = array('www.xxx.com')

to

$domain = array('localhost')

it doesnt get anything from mysql so just white page appears.
here is the some code that my config php files.

i will appreciate if i got any help..

config.inc.php

```
   <?php

$dir_server_root = str_replace( '/  ', '/', realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/..' ) . '/' );
    define( 'DIR_SERVER_ROOT', $dir_server_root );
    define( 'DIR_INCLUDES', DIR_SERVER_ROOT . 'inc/' );
    define( 'DIR_CLASSES', DIR_SERVER_ROOT . 'classes/' );
    define( 'DIR_LANGUAGES', DIR_SERVER_ROOT . 'languages/' );
    define( 'DEFAULT_LANG', 'tr' );
    define( 'LIVE', ( ( 'localhost' != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] && !preg_match( '/\.test/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) && !preg_match( '/local\./', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) );
    define( 'PROTOCOL', (getenv( 'HTTPS' ) ? 'https' : 'http') );
    define( 'SPHINX_SEARCH_LIMIT', 1000 );
    define( 'SPHINX_CONNECT_TIMEOUT', 0.100000000000000005551115 );
    define( 'MAIN_SYSTEM_EMAIL', 'xxxxxx@gmail.com' );
    $available_langs = array( 'tr' => 'Turkish' );
    require( DIR_INCLUDES . 'licence.php' );
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    if (!in_array( $host, $domains )) {
        $host_w = preg_replace( '/^(.*?)\./', '', $host );

        if (!in_array( $host_w, $domains )) {
            header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
            header( 'location: http://' . $domains[0] );
    exit(  );
}
}


if (( defined( 'LICENCE_EXPIRE_DATE' ) && LICENCE_EXPIRE_DATE < date( 'Y-m-d' ) )) {
exit(  );
}


if (LIVE) {
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE );
define( 'WINDOWS', 1 );
define( 'DIR_LIBS', DIR_SERVER_ROOT . 'libs/' );
define( 'DIR_FONTS', DIR_LIBS . 'Fonts/' );
define( 'DIR_TEMP', DIR_SERVER_ROOT . 'tmp/' );
define( 'SMARTY_LIBRARY', DIR_LIBS . 'Smarty/' );
define( 'SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR', DIR_LIBS . 'Lib9/smarty_plugins/' );
}
else {
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE );
define( 'WINDOWS', 1 );
define( 'DIR_LIBS', DIR_SERVER_ROOT . 'libs/' );
define( 'DIR_FONTS', '' );
define( 'DIR_TEMP', DIR_SERVER_ROOT . 'tmp/' );
define( 'SMARTY_LIBRARY', DIR_LIBS . 'Smarty/' );
define( 'SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR', DIR_LIBS . 'Lib9/smarty_plugins/' );
}
```

and
licence.php

```
<?php

$domains = array( 'www.xxx.com' );
define( 'ext_UpdateSoftware', 1 );
define( 'PRD_RELATED_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'MODULE_GROUPS_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'PAYU_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'MMB_GROUP_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'VPOS_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'INVOICE_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'ext_ImportExcel', 1 );
define( 'COUPON_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'XML_EXPORT_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'PRD_FILTERS_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'PRD_SETS_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'PRD_PAIRS_ENABLED', 1 );
define( 'OLD_TEMPLATE', 0 );
define( 'BOOK_MODE', 1 );
define( 'ext_facebook', 1 );
define( 'ext_ImportEmekKitap', 1 );
define( 'ext_ImportDeryaDagitim', 1 );
define( 'NEWSLETTER_ONLY_SMTP', 1 );
$arr_image_size['ProductImages'] = array( 'a' => '100x100', 'b' => '300x300', 'c' => '600x600' );
$arr_image_size['News'] = array( 'a' => '300x300', 'b' => '400x400' );
?>
```

Comment: Are you really asking us to fix a cracked script?

Comment: No no i am just asking for where is the problem and suggestion :S

Answer (score 0):

If you test your code (config.inc.php) you get:

```
DIR_SERVER_ROOT=C:\xampp/
DIR_INCLUDES=C:\xampp/inc/
live= (false)
```

So, you have to modify your script more.